# Ember App by default scrolls to the middle of the page

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm new to the Ember Framework and the community here :) I'm having a problem with my Ember App where for some reason by default it keeps scrolling to my `<div>` content instead of the components such as `{navbar}` in my `index.hbs` file before it.

Can't seem to understand why this is happening or how to begin fixing it. 
One thing I do notice is the section that it scrolls to by default is the only `div` content on the `index.hbs` page as the rest of the content is loaded through `{{components}}`. 
The reason why I didn't use a component for this section is because a controller by default allowed me to use createRecord to store my input values into a Firebase database.

Greatly appreciate any help :D

Hosted link - https://venturekpq.com

Source Files-
https://github.com/Christianq010/venturekpq_SPA-ember

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening not because of Ember specifically but because of an `autofocus` attribute you have on the input.

Rendered markup:

```
<input id="ember397" autofocus="" placeholder="Please type your e-mail address." type="email" class="form-control btn-input-secondary ember-view ember-text-field">
```

Check for this attribute being applied in the handlebars template. Remove it, or set it to false.

Comment: I copied code for the button from a tutorial and I had no clue the autofocus property did that, so I removed it :) Thank you !